# Don't Keep Activities + android phone number selection

Tags: android

I have an activity which is opening phone number selector using `startActivityForResult`, which is working fine in normal case.

When I don't keep Activities option is enabled and I am selecting any phone number and pressing back. My activity is not getting selected phone number.

After debugging of code, I found that my activity which call `startActivityForResult()` was destroyed when I move to phone number selector, and when coming back to same, new activity is created which doesn't know any result to be handled.

Need help to resolve this problem.

Comment: it is developer option for checking saveInstance and restore instance.if you want to resolve then please check the link  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

This is expected when you enable don't keep activities system will kill the activity as soon as it goes to background.

Comment: Thanks Sameer and Manish. :) 
my clients wants application to perform same in both case, but i don't have clue how to manage.